# Error on connecting excel to a oracle database

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to connect to a Oracle Database from a Excel 2010 in a Windows 2010 machine.
I installed [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) but when I try to connect to the database on

```
Data > From other sources > From database connection wizard > Other Advanced > Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle
```

I get this error message:

```
Not found cliente and network oracle componentes
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The "bitness" (64-bit or 32-bit) of your Oracle components needs to match the client tool - in this case Excel. You can check this in Excel from the menu: File / Help, then check the end of the line starting "Version: ".

Excel/Office is typically installed as 32-bit, so you may need to uninstall Oracle 64-bit, then install and configure Oracle 32-bit.